# MVC controllers/views/models moved now whole app is broken

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

I just inherited an MVC app that the previous programmer decided to reorganize by moving all the controllers, views, and models to subfolders within subfolders within... well, you get the idea.  Everything moved from the default root to "/Areas/Something/SomethingElse".

Now, each and every link clicked on results in a "Server Error in '/' application resource cannot be found (Microsoft's convoluted 404 error for MVC).

After hours of researching the default way resources are tracked down, I'm at wit's end.  I'd be willing to hardcode the references to the new locations if I could figure out where to do so.  A cleaner approach would seem to be able to tell MVC where the previous programmer re-rooted things.  I've seen some mention of being able to do this in global.asax but the documentation is as clear as mud.

Nothing I've googled or found on StackOverflow has helped.  I keep getting the 404 errors.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: It seems that step 1 would be to revert the codebase to a working version.  If "the previous programmer" checked in a change that broke the application then clearly that change should be un-done.

Comment: Thanks David but unfortunately a decision was made (administratively) to reorganize the entire solution.  On the surface this should be a harmless decision.  We reorganize all the time as part of our work as programmers.  The real problem here, IMHO, is MVC.  I've spent hours reading through their default methodologies for locating resources and it really makes me yearn for ASP.Net.  :-(

Comment: This *is* ASP.NET :) It sounds like the decision-maker either isn't technical leadership and this isn't his decision to make or he *is* technical leadership and he's making decisions without any knowledge of their impact. Either way, it's more a governance issue than a technical issue. Can you be more specific about the problem that you're seeing?  Controllers and models are compiled into the binary, so the folder location of the classes won't make a difference in the resulting output. And the runtime search folders for views are determined by the controller names. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: The original solution had the standard Views, Models, and Controllers folders with all the appropriate code/markup located there. At some point, the programmer redid this -- he replace created a custom folder called Areas and put 8 subfolders under that (A, B, C, etc. for example).  Underneath A, B, C etc., he then moved the Views, Models, and Controllers subfolders that originally lived in the application root.  With the new nesting, MVC can't locate anything -- we get 404 page not found errors on every link we click.

Comment: Sounds like he tried to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx  If he did it incorrectly then that should be fixed.  (Which may mean reverting the code and trying again.)  "Areas" can be used for organizing the code, but the framework's conventions still need to be followed.  (Hint: Not following framework conventions incurs tremendous technical debt for the company.  Another thing to which that decision-maker should be held accountable.)

Comment: Can you provide any more information about the error?  Is it unable to find the view, or unable to find the controller action?  Can you show an example controller, a request made for one of its actions, and the routing that's been configured for the application?

Comment: Thanks for your help David.  Because of the convoluted way controllers are responsible for views, it is impossible for me to say what is not actually being found -- IE simply reports the requested URL is not found.  In this example, the URL is "/Authentication/ForgotPassword".    Where this lives in the project is /Areas/Authentication/ForgotPassword.cshtml for the view.  There is no matching controller by name.  However there is a /Areas/Authentication/Login.cshtml view that uses @html.ActionLink to output two links to the web page for "ForgotPassword" and "Register". Those links give 404 err

Comment: So you can successfully view the `Login` page but it fails when you click on one of those links?  What is the URL in the browser when viewing the `Login` page?  What is the `Html.ActionLink` line of code which produces the links, and what is the resulting client-side link?  This may be a lot simpler than we're thinking :)  (Also, controllers aren't responsible for views, that's what makes it *not* convoluted.  If it's just a 404 Not Found error then that means the route (URL) being requested isn't able to map to a controller action.)

Comment: Hi David.  Not to sound argumentative, but the Wrox Professional MVC book I'm reading says every view is ultimately controlled by a controller -- they're not accessible directly. So that's why I made that (false?) claim :-(   ALL of the pages in the solution return 404s, the 2 I happened to pick render as /Authentication/ForgotPassword.  I tried changing the code to /Areas/Authentication/ForgotPassword but also got the 404 :-(

Comment: That statement is either taken out of context or incorrect.  Controllers pass control to views, but they don't "control" them.  Any view which isn't used by any logical result of a controller isn't used by the application and therefore can be deleted.  But controllers and views are de-coupled from one another and have no knowledge of one another.  A controller's responsibility is to invoke a business operation and return a result (sometimes to a view), and a view's responsibility is to display that result.  Both can operate independently.

Comment: I'm new enough to this I can't debate point effectively David so will have to defer.  I notice several points in the book that say views cannot be accessed directly -- it must be done through a controller -- and in fact I have tried this and in my own situations have found it to be true. If I type in the URL of a view (the cshtml file) directly, access is always prohibited in my case.  Regardless, It looks like I am stuck with a failed project :-(   Thanks so much for your help.